# Install a service created with VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, service, windows-services

I've to create a service in Visual Studio for one customer.

The customer IT service indicate me that they don't want any installer, only one exe that can be installed with instsrv.exe.

So I created a Service project on VS2010, compilated it(in 64 bits, it's an application that has to be ran in 64bits).

First problem: I didn't found any instsrv.exe, so I used InstallUtil.exe, the 64 bits version :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.xxxx\InstallUtil.exe "PathToMyGeneratedExe"
```

It says me that "`The commit phase completed successfully.`" and "`The transacted install has completed.`".

So I assume that the install completed successfully.

But if I go in the service console, I can't find the created service.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Does it give any errors? Or just success messages? If so, are you looking for the right name in the service console? What name did you give it in your project?

Comment: you could run InstallUtil with logfile option to get more information

Comment: @GeraldVersluis No errors messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallUtil is intended for usage with a service installer (which is really easy to make, but a bit buried) I imagine your client wasnt after a gui installer but I think it may be worth your while putting in the base serviceinstaller.

Normally InstallUtil will also prompt for a user to run the service under as well. if you havent got this you probably arent installed

Take a read of http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/23/windows-services-in-c-adding-the-installer-part-3/ for details of how to do this

(TLDR right click on your service design surface and add installer)

Comment: and instsrv need also a serviceInstaller project? Because I found some links that weren't specifying any service installer projects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-CH/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @j4n cant say ive ever used instsrv, it may not need an installer. However if you want to test it with installutil you will need the installer